# cloud9-ide Set of the URL in the "Preview with web server"

Tags: cloud9-ide

I use c9.io (Micro plan) to program on an external web server in PHP. The integration is done via ssh. 
Problem:
With "preview with web server" I would like to set a different URL and port. Where can I do this? When I type up a url in the address bar, it will be ignored.
Example:

When you click on "preview with web server" indicates the internal browser https://34.56.78.90. But I want http://34.56.78.90/test.php (port 80)

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 does not allow you to set a different preview URL or port. It uses port 8080 so deploy on that.